# Unequal distribution of n things among p persons

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is from Higher Algebra by Hall & Knight.

> In how many ways can $n$ things be given to $p$ persons, when there is
>   no restriction as to the number of things each may receive?  Answer:
>   $p^n$

If 3 things and 2 person then only two ways possible

1. 1 thing to 1st person, 2 things to 2nd person
2. 2 things to 1st person and 1 thing to 2nd person

but according to the answer given in the text it should be $2^3=8$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that there are n things.
For the first thing, we can give it to one of p people.
For the 2nd thing, we can give it to one of p people.
Similar procedure can be applied to all n things.
Using fundamental principle of counting,
total number of possible combinations are

p*p*p .... n terms = $p^n$

Answer (score 0):

What about not giving the first person anything? Count your cases correctly.

Comment: (1,2),(2,1),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(1,1)=9 ways?

Comment: Are you assuming the three things are identical?  What if the three things are an apple, a banana and a pear?

Answer (score 0):

This is problem number 9 from page 126, Examples XI. b.

The original solution of this problem from page 40 of [Solutions of the Examples in Higher Algebra (LaTeX Edition) by Hall and Knight](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/150876350X) is [image]

Comment: Indian Edition : http://www.flipkart.com/solutions-examples-higher-algebra-latex-edition-english/p/itme6krr9pfvv3ap?pid=9781508763505

Comment: http://www.amazon.in/dp/150876350X